Does $f(x + o(1/n)) = f(x) +o(1/n)$ holds if $f$ is a real-valued continuous function?
If $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, then we may invoke Taylor's expansion and claim that $f(x+o(1/n)) \approx f(x) + \nabla f_x^T o(1/n) $, if $\nabla f$ is bounded, then we have $f(x + o(1/n)) \approx f(x) + o(1/n)$. Does the same statement holds for continuity without assuming differentiability? Write $h_n = o(1/n) $, I'm trying to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(f(x+h_n)-f(x)) = 0$, but I'm a bit stuck on where to go. Not sure if this actually holds.

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ near $x=0$, where the derivatives does not exist at $x=0$; or $f(x)$ as Brownian motion, where $f(x)$ is always continuous but the derivatives does not exist anywhere.

This argument has lots of problems. You write that $f$ has domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ but then write $f'(x)$ as if it is a number. Differentiability is not sufficient to invoke Taylor's theorem. "$f'(x)$ is bounded" is not meaningful because $f'(x)$ is a number. Your use of $\simeq$ does not lend itself to making your argument precise. $o(1/n)$ is not a function and you may not just "write $h_n = o(1/n)$" as if it were a number.

Can you say a little bit more about what you even mean by $f(x+o(1/n))$? Something like $f(x+h(n))$ where $h(n) = o(1/n)$? What is $n$, then? If you just mean something like $f(x+1/n)$ where $x$ and $n$ are free to vary then I think the examples below may help.

Try it with a function that is not differentiable, say $f(x)=x^{1/p}$ at $x=0$. Then the limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty} nh_n^{1/p}$ which you'll find doesn't go to 0 even if $h_n$ is $o(1/n)$, e.g. if $h_n=1/n^2$ then the limit will be $\infty$ for $p>2$.

What about $f(x) = x^3$? Take the derivative at $x=n$ and see if this does not answer your question.
ETA: Or more precisely,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\Big(\Big(n+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^3-n^3\Big) = \theta(1).$$
If you want $x$ fixed while $n$ goes to $\infty$ then a simple $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$; $\alpha < 1$ will certainly do around the neighborhood of $x=0$.

No, we may take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $x=0$.
Then, $f(0)=0$ and $f(0+1/n^2)=f(1/n^2)=\dfrac{1}{n}$.
This expression is not $o(1/n)$ since $$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=1\to 1\neq 0$$
